# Crop selected image in circular shape, Before sending it to the server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

I searched for that, But most of what I found was either dead/not supported for old browsers/cropping images in rectangular shape.

I want something similar to Facebook feature for uploading profile pictures, The user selects an image, If that image doesn't exceed specific dimensions it would be displayed and then the user drag the highlighted rectangle and crop the image.

But instead of rectangular shape, I need circular shape.

So if I have an input to browse/upload an image:

```
<input type="file" class="sr-only" id="input" name="image" accept="image/*">
```

After the user selects an image, Either on the same place or on a popup the user would be able to drag the highlighted circular shape and then click `Crop`.

So the most important parts are:

- The image is cropped in circular shape.
- Supported for most browsers including mobile/tablet/ipad browsers.
- The ability to upload the cropped image to the server using PHP.

I know that the platform is for helping with errors and bugs, But as I said I searched first and want to ask here, As there are many developers here that some of them could have been in the same situation and found the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply looking to crop the image, you probably want to use Clipping and Masking. What this does is it crops the image in a certain shape. here is an example of code you could use:

```css
.crop {
 clip-path: circle(60px at center);
}
```

```html
<img src="src.png">
```

from here you could do what you need to make the clipping mask draggable.  hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, But what if there are many objects/people in the image? I want the user to be able to select the area to crop as circular shape

Comment: You can use http://interactjs.io/ (which is a pretty good library) to make your image larger or smaller, and draggable.  The clipping path will stay the same size, 60px, but as the user resizes the image to be larger, the area clipped becomes more zoomed in.